# Cell identifier number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

I need to use a SUM function over an Excel range, for example, `=SUM(A12:A25)`.

Is there a way to store the numbers `12` and `25` in another two cells and use them in the SUM function?

Comment: No. you can't store cell range in variables. My suggestion : use macro, or describe more details what is you need and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @pnuts this really _has_ to be a duplicate, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, For example you might put `12` in B1 and `25` in B2 and apply:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&B1&":A"&B2))
```

[INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

> Returns the reference specified by a text string. References are immediately evaluated to display their contents. Use INDIRECT when you want to change the reference to a cell within a formula without changing the formula itself.

Comment: +1 Just know this method. I Thought it can't be done with variables as your answer. I found this question from triage review. Sorry for my missunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `INDIRECT`, you should use `INDEX` because it is not volatile. If B1 shows the first row and B2 the last one then your formula would be:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,B1):INDEX(A:A,B2))
```

If B1 is 5 and B2 is 7, then it will sum B5:B7 (and as said, in a not volatile way). In over 90% of the cases `INDEX()` and `INDEX():INDEX()` will be a better solution than `OFFSET` and/or `INDIRECT`. ;)